# Can't install Google Earth Engine plugin QGIS 3.16?

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, qgis-plugins, error

When I try to install the Google Earth Engine plugin in QGIS 3.16 I have this message:

**"Couldn't load plugin 'ee_plugin' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method "**

Comment: Well, have you contacted the provider of the plugin? Have you checked bug and error reports?

Comment: The QGIS 3.16 had some API changes which were not backward-compatible. This bug has been fixed, try reinstalling to the v0.0.3 as suggested by @Spacedman. It's better report bugs as issues here https://github.com/gee-community/qgis-earthengine-plugin/issues instead of on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

This error has been reported and there's a fix at the github site which I guess will make its way to the qgis plugins site in due course:

https://github.com/gee-community/qgis-earthengine-plugin/issues/76

Always check the project pages!